# IIS hangs on specific route requests in ASP.NET MVC 3 app UNLESS running in debugger

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, iis-7.5

We have a very strange issue that we're dealing with.

We have an MVC 3 application that we are still developing, and Monday we started running into an issue with four specific routes (methods) in one of our controllers.  All four of these routes are used in the management of roles and deal with either creating or editing a role.  We have two different tiers of roles in the application, so there are two routes for creating a role for each tier, and two routes for editing a role for each tier.  Both methods for the corresponding create routes call the same view, as well as the two methods for the corresponding edit routes.  Both views call a shared partial view that contains the form fields that correspond to the properties of the role being created or edited.

Here's the issue.

If I attempt to hit these routes without running the debugger first, IIS will hang.  It will not error out, throw an error, or even register the request in the IIS log.

HOWEVER, if I attempt to access those routes in the debugger, regardless of whether I have a breakpoint set up or not, the routes function as they should.

To make life a little more interesting, if I attempt to access those same routes AFTER I've run and shut down the debugger, the routes STILL function as they should.

We can reproduce this behavior on EVERY machine on our development team AND our staging server (except the debugging part on staging).

The methods that correspond to all of these routes themselves rely on a couple of methods in the same web service in our middle tier.  Those methods work properly outside of the debugger in our integration tests.

We've checked for endless loops in the code, but can't find anything that would create an endless loop under these conditions.  In fact, there's only one loop in the shared view, but it's a for each loop which shouldn't ever result in an endless loop.

Lastly, when I attempt to hit any of these four routes without running under the debugger or at least running it on a previous request, IIS essentially hangs.  It will not time out.  It will not throw an error.  It will not log an error to the IIS log.  Finally, it will eat up system resources the the point that you have to either restart IIS or reboot the entire machine.

Has anyone ever seen this behaviour before?  Any ideas on how to get around it?  I've NEVER seen this behavior before, and the only thing that anyone in our development group could come up with was some sort of permissions issue on a file, but we're not accessing the file system (outside of the view files themselves, and they have proper permissions) at any point during the processing of these methods.

I'm open to any and all suggestions.

### **UPDATE #1:**

I have also posted this question on the ASP.NET forums and I had someone ask a question for more information.  Here's my response to their questions.

> What IIS are we talking about?

IIS 7.5.  We're using the full-fledged IIS, not IIS Express.

> What error?

That's just it.  There is no error.  No error is being reported.  In fact, the request itself isn't being recorded in the IIS log for the site IF we're attempting to access these routes without the debugger running.  If the debugger is running, everything works as you would expect it to.

> VS Cassini?

Nope.  IIS 7.5 that comes with Windows 7.

> If you deploy on IIS a default WebForm project , does it works?

Yes.  Without an issue.  I actually have a number of WebForms applications that I maintain for customers running on my development box.  They all work without any issue whatsoever.

> If you deploy on IIS a default MVC project , does it works?

Yes.  I have a number of sites running on this box.  All of these sites are running without a hitch.  IN FACT, the vast majority of routes on this site can be accessed without any issue.  The vast majority of routes **WITHIN THIS VERY CONTROLLER** can be accessed without any issue!!!

To reiterate, this controller allows a user to manage users, roles, and permissions within the application.  We have methods in there for listing, creating, and updating users, roles, and permissions.  The routes that hit the methods for managing users and permissions work regardless of whether the debugger is running or not.  The ONLY routes giving us issues are the four routes that I described above.

We currently have 19 controllers in this application, each with a varying number of defined route methods.  EVERY OTHER route defined for the application is working properly and is not exhibiting this behavior.  These are the only four methods (routes) in this one particular controller where we are seeing this.

### **UPDATE #2:**

I've narrowed this down to a REST call (to a service that we control) within the controller.  Here's the weird part - if I go into the REST service and immediately return a value (don't process anything), it still hangs outside of the debugger.  If I'm running inside of the debugger or immediately after running the debugger, everything works as it should.

If I attempt to hit that REST service in fiddler directly, it works like a charm.

I'm going to try changing the URL in the service contract for the web service I'm calling and see if that works.  Maybe it's something to do with the REST URL on the web service.

### **UPDATE #3:**

Just to add further confusion, I set up Fiddler to act as a proxy between my MVC application and the REST middle tier.  For EVERY other REST call within the application, the proxy gets the request.  For this particular REST call, the proxy NEVER gets the request.

Now here's the annoying part.  The WebChannelFactory that we use to call all of the methods in the middle tier through REST is created using a utility class in our MVC application.  This code is used to generate every channel, so there's no difference between the requests that populate the list of users and the one that populates the list of permissions (the one that's hanging).

This is a GET request that's hanging, so I was able to call it directly in the browser.  It works without an issue.  The issues doesn't appear to be on the service end, but somewhere in the MVC application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure that you don't pass in ViewBag.Variable.ToString(), since it's dynamic, it will not work!

Comment: That was it.  I was passing a GUID into the service, but I was assigning it to the ViewBag first and then using ViewBag.Id.ToString() to get the string representation of the Id.  Why it didn't error out still baffles me, but going back to my original Guid and calling ToString() on it solved the problem.